# How do I change the way (order) in which content on my Angular site are displayed

Tags: angular

I have this massive angular project that I inherited.

The site is extremely slow when loading for the first time and upon troubleshooting, the problem appears to be the way the files are loaded.

A quick look at the waterfall diagram and it appears that the issue is that the look and feel are only displayed after the third batch of loading (highlighted in white ink).

I strongly believe that if I am able to make the content in the third batch load first, it will significantly speed up the "percieved" site speed.

I have tried to re-arrange the contents of my app components to no avail.[image: Water fall diagram]

I will appreciate any help I can get in achieving this objective.

Thank you.

Angular Cli : 1.6.4
Node : 8.11.3

Comment: as I can guess you are using angular dev configuration to record that result. do you use the same configuration on a prod? could you run deve server with prod flag like this `ng serve --prod` and provide one more screen of the nework tab, and performance recorded during app start would also be very helpfull

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @anrei. It was about the same effect. I ran `ng serve -e=prod`

Comment: there is no such alias `-e` on ng-serve. is it a misstype?

Comment: Works for me :(

Comment: this hude piece of black empty network(no reqeuests in progress) makes me think that your app is running in JIT mode and a lot of computations is happening. could you check if that is true? if yo don't know how - try to make a record on the performance dev tools tab